# Sorting suggested edits stats by rejected sorts in order rather than reverse order

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, sorting

All of the sorts on the suggested edit stats page sort in reverse order (newest to oldest) except for when sorting by "[rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=all&tab=Rejected)" (10k MSE reputation required).

I've reproduced this on four sites including MSE.

Please fix this sort to match all of the others and show items from most recent to oldest.

Comment: Anonymous > week also shows oldest to newest to me.